# Customize approval process "unable to submit" page

Tags: approval-process

in the flow of an approval process, Is there a way to customize the page, for a "Unable to Submit for Approval" information? I would like to know, to see in which approval was this denied, and what condition wasnt meet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no applicable active approval processes, the standard submit for approval button will show a standard error message.  This cannot be changed to my knowledge.

If you instead use a custom button to launch a flow, you could

a) use a flow decision element to determine if the criteria are met, and if not, show a custom screen with your message.  If criteria are met, you can submit for approval via flow.

b) (maybe) try to submit for approval and catch the error with a fault path, but this may have other issues, have not tried it.

Comment: ok. I guess thats the best possible answer. Thanks